# Loop over columns of data frame and populate another column if condition matched

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
> df
POP A   B   C   D   E
NA  CC  CC  TC  TT  CC
NA  TG  TT  TT  TT  TG
NA  TT  TA  TT  TT  TT
NA  CC  CC  TC  TT  CC
NA  TC  TT  TT  TT  TT
NA  AG  GG  GG  GG  AG
NA  AA  AA  AG  AG  AA
NA  GG  GA  GG  AA  GG
NA  AA  AA  AA  AT  AA
```

I need to loop over columns `A` to `E`, and populate the first column `POP` when a condition is matched in the other columns. In particular, I'd like to have this result:

```
> df
POP A   B   C   D   E
C/T CC  CC  TC  TT  CC
G/T TG  TT  TT  TT  TG
A/T TT  TA  TT  TT  TT
C/T CC  CC  TC  TT  CC
C/T TC  TT  TT  TT  TT
A/G AG  GG  GG  GG  AG
A/G AA  AA  AG  AG  AA
A/G GG  GA  GG  AA  GG
A/T AA  AA  AA  AT  AA
```

So, when the first column with two different letters is found, print the two letters in the `POP` column separated by `/` in alphabetical order.

The real data frame has 700 columns and 10000 rows.

Comment: That looks like a basic exercise from college. Seems quite easy, so think a little please.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
ind <- apply(sapply(df[-1], function(x) grepl('([A-Z])\\1', x)),
              1,
              function(y) match(FALSE, y))

ind
#[1] 3 1 2 3 1 1 3 2 4

mapply(function(i, j)
    if (!is.na(j))
        paste(sort(strsplit(levels(df[[j]])[df[i, j]], '')[[1]]),
              collapse='/')
    else
        j,
    seq_along(ind), ind + 1)
#[1] "C/T" "G/T" "A/T" "C/T" "C/T" "A/G" "A/G" "A/G" "A/T"
```